# Query from query result in foreach

Tags: php, mysql

so i have this function

```
public function GetNearAirport($adr)
{


    $acftrange = $this->GetAcftAdr($adr);
    $too = array();
    foreach ($acftrange as $key) {

        $result = $this->GetNearRange($adr,$key->range);



    }
```

The $acftrange give me some rows, and i need to get a new result for each row of $acftrange. But i need all results in one array So I can insert into the html table. Sorry for my english. In foreach the $key->range is a condition for the query to be made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume `getNearRange()` returns an array. Use `array_merge` to append `$result` to `$too`

```
foreach ($acftrange as $key) {
    $result = $this->GetNearRange($adr,$key->range);
    $too = array_merge($too, $result);
}
```